# What is the build method in StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have three questions:

1. What is the *use* of the [`build`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget/build.html) method when we extend [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html)?
2. Why should we override it and what is present in it before overriding the `build` method?
3. Is `build` a constructor sort of thing in `StatelessWidget`?

Answer (score 0):

## Stateful and stateless widgets

According to the [flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive)

A widget is either stateful or stateless. If a widget can change—when a user interacts with it, for example—it’s stateful.

A stateless widget never changes. Icon, IconButton, and Text are examples of stateless widgets. Stateless widgets subclass `StatelessWidget`.

A stateful widget is dynamic: for example, it can change its appearance in response to events triggered by user interactions or when it receives data. `Checkbox`, `Radio`, `Slider`, `InkWell`, `Form`, and `TextField` are examples of stateful widgets. Stateful widgets subclass `StatefulWidget`.

A widget’s state is stored in a `State` object, separating the widget’s state from its appearance. The state consists of values that can change, like a slider’s current value or whether a checkbox is checked. When the widget’s state changes, the state object calls `setState()`, telling the framework to redraw the widget.

- A stateful widget is implemented by two classes: a subclass of
  StatefulWidget and a subclass of State.
- The state class contains the widget’s mutable state and the widget’s
  build() method.
- When the widget’s state changes, the state object calls setState(),
  telling the framework to redraw the widget.
- The `StatefulWidget` and `StatelessWidget` are abstract classes which
  have implemented the `build()` method and  as you extending the
  `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget` class you must override and
  implement the methods which declared in those abstract classes.

Comment: Hope it will useful